# Uploading file as binary with Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone.js to upload files to an S3 endpoint, and it seems to only accept files as a binary. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

What I'm looking to do is the equivalent of this in Postman:

[image]

Comment: Your question's unclear, to me at least.

Comment: @jarmod check the image I added, see if that clarifies a bit.